# Access to all states of angular-ui-router programmatically

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I have a `$stateProvider` configured like this:

```js
angular.module('example', ['ui.router'])
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/steps");
    $stateProvider.state('steps', {
        url: '/steps',
        templateUrl: 'steps.html',
        controller: function($scope, $state) {
          $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
            $scope.currentStep = toState.data && toState.data.stepNumber;
          });
          if ($state.is('steps')) {
            $state.go('.first');
          }
        }
      })
      .state('steps.first', {
        url: '/first',
        template: 'First',
        data: {
          stepNumber: 0
        },
      })
      .state('steps.second', {
        url: '/second',
        template: 'Second',
        data: {
          stepNumber: 1
        },
      })
      .state('steps.third', {
        url: '/third',
        template: 'third',
        data: {
          stepNumber: 2
        },
      });
  });
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['example']);
});
```

```css
ul { list-style: none; }
li { display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="steps.html">
  <h2>{{ currentStep }}</h2>
  <div ui-view></div>
  <button ng-if="currentStep !== 0">Prev</button>
  <button>Next</button>
</script>
<div>
  <h1>Example</h1>
  <ul>
    <li><a ui-sref="steps.first">goTo First</a>
    </li>
    <li><a ui-sref="steps.second">goTo Second</a>
    </li>
    <li><a ui-sref="steps.third">goTo Third</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

What I want to do now, is to have the buttons automatically point to the next/prev step, end the next button should vanish if the last step is reached. Sadly this example seems not to be working on stack overflow, so I also created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0yn632Lv/) version of this example

**UPDATE**

For Clarification: I want something dynamic, so that I don't have to change the code if the order of the steps is changed, steps are removed, or new steps are added.

Comment: `<button ng-if= "currentStep !== 2">Next</button>`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gjcg596b/1/

Comment: I want it to be dynamic, this won't work id I add steps, and the buttons still won't work

Answer (score 0):

It isn't really clean but you can just generate your state name in function of your current step.

Link a function changeStep() that will take a delta in params and do something like this

```
 $scope.changeStep = function (delta) {
      var newStep = $scope.currentStep + delta;
      var stateName = "steps.";

      switch (newStep){
           case 1:
              stateName += "first";
              break;
            etc...
       }

       $state.go(stateName);
 }
```

So in your template steps.html do this

```
   <button ng-if="currentStep !== 0" ng-click="changeStep(-1)">Prev</button>
   <button ng-click="changeStep(1)" ng-if="currentStep !== 2">Next</button>
```

Comment: this would work, but it is not as dynamic as I'd like, I want the buttons independent of the steps, so that I can change steps, but I wouldn't have to change the buttons.

Comment: The only solution in order to avoid the switch is to change your step name and use "step.1" so the change step function will be `$state.go(stateName+newStep)`

Comment: But how would I detect the last step with dynamically created steps